# Symfony2 protect admin panel with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

i have a web project developed with Symfony2 and i would like to protect my admin panel by BOT's continuos scan. Now there is just a simple authentication with username and password but i would like set also a .htaccess and .htpasswd authentication.

Usually we have to put the .htaccess file inside the folder to protect but with Symfony2 i don't have a folder where is located the admin panel to protect.

I didn't found any other posts with the same issue. Someone known some way to do what i wrote above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using RESTful URLs, you're probably out of luck.

Apache still parses the .htaccess if you create a folder path with the same names, but these will only be valid for the files actually in there and not for the REST-'fallback'. You'll have to find an symfony2-solution, e.g. implementing a login system and edit the corresponding files.

Not sure about this, but if you *have* a login system and think it's not secure enough, you probably should think about your security at first. However, if you still want http auth, [you can do it via php](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) also.

Comment: I think that my login system is secure but i wouldn't find thousands of logs inside my apache log because some bot try to find my username, password and captcha security. However seems that is not possibile protect it with the .htaccess file. The only way seems to be change the admin url with a unthinkable url.

Comment: Security by obscurity is not the way to go here. You'd still find a lot of 404's in your log, a .htaccess log won't change that in any way. If you login url isn't /wplogin.php (that's ~10% in my log and I never used Wordpress!), there's few profit for using this. Just use a grep to hide the attempts while viewing the logs, that's kind of background noise of the web. Keep your logs though, maybe you'll need to scan them for a hacker once.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it's a right advice. I didn't solve my doubt but maybe there isn't a way to resolve it.

Comment: @Nothing You'll always see someone scanning your site, brute forcing you ssh ... this is just usual. Only thing you can do is trying to prevent their success with captchas, iptables blocking and stuff like this. Double login won't help much, they will still scan and try to find vulnerabilitys. Anyway, if this answer helped you please mark it as such (;